# Complex MySQL join statement

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I realize there are many MySQL posts on here and each is specific to the posters use.  I have a fairly complex join situation.

I have 3 tables and am attempting to aggregate data on two columns. Im grouping on ProductID and ProductionMonth.

I am almost there but am having a sticking point now with the grouping of the date column for my data set.

My data output is currently not filling in data where there isnt any for a particular month.  And I NEED it to at least display zeros and the date instead.

Right now the output is something like this:

```
<pre>
Products    TOTAL   CANCELLED   Product Name    ProductType     ProductionMonth 
    2        32          5        Advantage        VSC Auto       2016-02-02
    2        26          3        Advantage        VSC Auto       2016-01-01
    2        31          2        Advantage        VSC Auto       2015-12-01
    16        5          1          ASC          VSC Auto         2016-02-01
    16        4          4          ASC          VSC Auto         2016-01-01
    17        0          0       MenuVantage    Menu Software     NULL
    21       12          0          CSO             Credit        2016-02-01
    21       24          0          CSO             Credit        2016-01-01
</pre>
```

But I need the data to also include the date even if there isnt a date associated with that record.  Here is my current code:

```
<pre>
SELECT P.Products, Inv.TOTAL,Inv.CANCELLED, Pur.ProductName AS 'Product Name',ProductType,ProductionMonth
FROM Dealership_Products P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductsID, SUM(Total) AS TOTAL, SUM(Cancelled) AS CANCELLED,ProductionMonth
          FROM Monthly_Production_Numbers 
           WHERE DealershipID = '25'
           AND
           ProductionMonth > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
           GROUP BY ProductionMonth,ProductsID) AS Inv
ON P.Products = Inv.ProductsID
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT ProductsID, ProductName AS ProductName, ProductType
            FROM Products 
            GROUP BY ProductsID) AS Pur
ON P.Products = Pur.ProductsID
WHERE DealershipID = '25'
AND
Inactive = 'FALSE'
ORDER BY Products ASC, ProductionMonth DESC
</pre>
```

Tables being used:

```
Dealership_Products
  column (Products)  ->      
Products.ProductsID
```

Monthly_Production_Numbers
  group by (ProductionMonth) "last 3 months"
  group by (ProductsID)

Products

Due to the data and tables being so complex I am not able to share all the structure.  But the main parts are here.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best handled in the presentation layer (e.g. a PHP loop) if that's available.

Comment: It is available, but I know its possible to get the full gamut with some clever MySQL lines as well.  Would be more efficient if going the MySQL route.  thanks.

Comment: No. There's no efficiency gain per se.

Comment: True, I meant in the lines of code needed to deliver the desired results.  Perhaps in a more elegant way.  ;)

Comment: We have differing definitions of elegance :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about using IFNULL?

```
IFNULL(ProductionMonth,'date-you-want') as ProductionMonth
```

Comment: Not sure where you are suggesting I place the IFNULL line you mentioned.  I assume within the SELECT line.  Tried, and same results.  Thanks!

Comment: You'd still need some mechanism for generating the IFNULL value (note that COALESCE() conforms to the standard). This could be via a UNION, or a utility table (e.g. a table of all possible dates, or a table of integers [0-9]) - something to act as the seed for generating the missing values. But my preference is a loop in the application layer.

Comment: Do you have any code examples or suggestions on how to iterate through my above output example and fill in the missing lines with the dates via some form of application layer?